# After upgrade Ubuntu starts into black screen

Tags: 14.04, startup, radeon

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and a XFX Radeon HD 7970.

My system was running fine but after the last upgrade (26 September 2014), I'm not able to restart. The system is loading (I can see part of a Teamviewer window which is a program opening at the start of the system).

The rest of the screen is black and I have a cross cursor.
I have access to the command line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In my system the same thing happened in VirtualBox. Seems that the login window is no longer started automatically. I logged on via the command line.

Do not know a permanent fix but in my case `sudo lightdm` popped up my login window and I could work again.

Comment: @Hans `sudo start lightdm` (or `sudo service lightdm start`), if it works, may be considered preferable to `sudo lightdm` since it runs LightDM in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The AMD driver for the Radeon card I had installed was the beta version. When I updated ubuntu, this was not compatible anymore. 
I then had to remove the driver from tty1 console and was then able to reboot.